# Preference Votes Data to Groups

Tags: excel, vba, statistics

I have a problem creating a formula or VBA macro that sorts 'preference voting' data into appropriate groups for students selecting summer camp electives. Historically, we've done the voting and sorting on paper, and i'd like to move to something a little less time consuming for the many, many rounds of electives we do at camp.

Ive created a form they fill out, which gives me a spreadsheet with their elective preferences. it looks like this

```
Kids    A   B   C
1001    2   3   1
1002    3   1   2
1003    3   1   2
1004    3   1   2
1005    3   1   2
1006    3   1   2
1007    3   2   1
1008    3   2   1
1009    2   1   3
1010    3   1   2
1011    2   1   3
```

what id like to be able to do is run a macro or (even better) a dynamic function that sorts the voters into categories - like this

```
A       B       C
1001    1002    1007
1010    1003    1008
1011    1004    1009
        1005    
        1006
```

basically - elective A has no first choice votes so its initial count = 0. Elective B has 8 first choice votes, so its initial count is 8, elective c has 3 first choice votes so its initial count is 3. I need these to be at least close to balanced (plus i actually have over 100 students), so we have 2nd choices also (3rd is a strike). so the minimum count for each group needs to be 1/4 + 1 total voting population.

Obviously no solution is perfect, because theres an inherently subjective choice about who gets moved from their first choice to their second, but any help would be appreciated.

If theres something in stat math that would point me in the right direction that would help too. ive tried googling this, but all references to voting systems i can find assume i want to anonymise the data, which is the opposite of what i need.

ive tried vlookups and indexing, but the formulas quickly get unwieldy, and dont seem to do what i need anyway. SORT functions seem to be the way to go, but i cant wrap my head around the syntax of them (using just visual sort is how ive rendered the above sorting.) RANK doesnt seem to offer what im looking for.

Comment: have them fill out a sheet with their preferences for electives(a, b, or c) on them, then sort them into groups of those electives (basically to create a roster for each elective).

Comment: Sorry, im not being clear. Each student ranks 3 electives from (1) most preferred to (3) not preferred. each elective will take place at the same time.
1001 is a reference to a student. the first pseudo table column is the list of students. the second through fourth columns represent electives. The data residing there indicate a preference for each of the electives. what i want is an autogenerated list of what students will attend each elective. Ill have to this sort 10 times over the next couple of weeks, and id like to not have to do it by hand.

Comment: I still don't get it... on your example, not one student voted for A first, but you still put 3 students at A... I don't get your reasoning...

Comment: A group needs to have students, to keep B and C instructors from having the whole student population. So i gave students 1001, 1010, 1011 their second choice.

Comment: @cecilgol, I get what you are trying to do but as you said no solution is perfect :/ I think there will have to be some final human decision making involved in the process in order to make this happen. I will give it a try in Excel and see where I am at and post an answer if I get close to achieving what you need.

Comment: @pnuts please see my vba solution below. There might have been more advanced techniques to solve this but I think mine works out OK for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have simulated the voting process and created *somehow* equal groups of kids based on their preferred choices.

If anything is unclear please leave a comment and I will do my best to better explain the content.

**Note(disclaimer hehe)**: *I would have done this using only Types, Collections and arrays, however the ability to demonstrate visual representation of my solution required me  to use spreadsheet. The code used in this example can easily be modified not to work with spreadsheets but Collections.*

Here's what I have done in steps:

- 1 - Setup spreadsheet (*spreadsheet name:*   **`"Sheet1"`**, *module name*: **`Formatting`**)
- 2 - Randomized Voting Process (*module name:*   **`RandomVotes`**)
- 3 - Calculations Step 1 (*module name:*   **`Step1`**)
- 4 - Calculations Step 2 (*module name:*   **`Step2`**)

## Step 1

**Note**: *you can **skip this step and step2** if you already have the results of voting in the following format*:

- `Kids` is column **`A`**
- `A` is column **`B`**
- `B` is column **`C`**
- `C` is column **`D`**

Your initial spreadsheet should look like the below screenshot

[image: setup]

You can manually make it look like this although I have recorded a macro that formats your spreadsheet to the standards required for the macro to work properly. Copy-paste the below code to a new module and rename it(*rename the module*) to **`Formatting`** execute the below code(*press* <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute)

```
Sub FormatSpreadsheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Consolas"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Consolas"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Kids"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "A"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "B"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0001"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0002"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0003"
    Range("A2:A4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A47"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A2:A47").Select
    Range("B1:D1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Columns("A:P").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("B1:D1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("H7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B:D,F:F,G:G,H:H,J:J,K:K,L:L,N:N,O:O,P:P").Select
    Range("P1").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Range("B1:D1,F1:H1,J1:L1,N1:P1").Select
    Range("N1").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1st choice"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2nd choice"
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3rd choice"
    Range("E:E,I:I,M:M").Select
    Range("M1").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 12.13
    Range("E1:H1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("E1:H1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("I1:L1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("E1:H1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("M1:P1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13434879
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("E1,I1,M1").Select
    Range("M1").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You spreadsheet now should like like the below screenshot

[image: formatted spreadsheet]

**Note**: *column* **`A`** *goes down to number* **`0046`** (*row 47*) *so, if you have more kids then add more numbers before continuing.*

## Step 2

Add a new **`Module`** and name it **`RandomVotes`**

Copy-Paste and then execute (<kbd>F5</kbd>) the code to get results.

*The code will simulate a voting process and print results in columns `B` to `D`:*

```
Sub RandomizeVotes()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim r As Range, nxtRnd As Long
    Dim rowComplete As Boolean

    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range("B" & i)
        r = GetRandom
        Do Until rowComplete
            r.Offset(0, 1) = GetRandom
            r.Offset(0, 2) = GetRandom
            If r <> r.Offset(0, 1) And r <> r.Offset(0, 2) And r.Offset(0, 1) <> r.Offset(0, 2) Then rowComplete = True
        Loop
        Set r = Nothing
        rowComplete = False
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetRandom() As Long
    Randomize
    Dim x As Double
    x = Rnd
    If x < 0.3 Then
        GetRandom = 1
    ElseIf x >= 0.3 And x < 0.6 Then
        GetRandom = 2
    ElseIf x >= 0.6 Then
        GetRandom = 3
    End If
End Function
```

At this point, go back to your spreadsheet it should give you the following results:

[image: randomized voting]

**Note:** *I said you can skip this step if you already have your voting results in the format specified above. I would recommend following all steps just to see* **how things work**.

## Step3

Add a new **`Module`**, name it **`Step1`**.

Copy-Paste the below code and again: execute it.

*This code will populate columns* **`F:P`** *based on kids choices*

```
Option Explicit

' Choices columns
Sub Step_1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Range

    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range("B" & i)

        ' first choices
        If r = 1 Then
            r.Offset(0, 4) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, 1) = 1 Then
            r.Offset(0, 5) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, 2) = 1 Then
            r.Offset(0, 6) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        End If

        ' second choices
        If r = 2 Then
            r.Offset(0, 8) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, 1) = 2 Then
            r.Offset(0, 9) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, 2) = 2 Then
            r.Offset(0, 10) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        End If

        ' third choices
        If r = 3 Then
            r.Offset(0, 12) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, 1) = 3 Then
            r.Offset(0, 13) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        ElseIf r.Offset(0, 2) = 3 Then
            r.Offset(0, 14) = r.Offset(0, -1).Text
        End If

        Set r = Nothing
    Next i

    deleteEmpties

End Sub


Private Sub deleteEmpties()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        For j = 16 To 6 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then Cells(i, j).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

The result should look similar to the below screenshot (*if you have randomized choices than it will look different*)

[image: choices columns 3 variations]

## Step 4

Add a new **`Module`**, name it **`Step2`**.

Copy-Paste the below code and again: execute it.

*This code will **re**-populate columns* **`F:H`**. *This pretty much (and hopefully **`;)`** )* ***achieves what you were looking for***.

At this point, your column **`F:H`** are sorted by kids numbers. To add more although intentional randomness to the process you can ***re-sort*** the numbers. For example instead of

```
0002
0005
0010
0013
0017
0021
0022
0025
0026
0038
0043
```

you can do

```
0038
0005
0026
0013
0017
0022
0021
0002
0010
0025
0043
```

You will see what I mean when we get to the algorithm that will even out the groups.

My solution to even out the groups of kids:

- find out roughly how many kids per group ( total / 3 )
- find group with the highest preferred count
- get the first in the list [*starting from the end of the list*] (*thats why randomizing columns order may be a good idea*)
- find kid's second choice and move him to that column

for example:

[image: explanation]

Since the group B is the highest preferred group we need to move some people off of it in order to even out the other ones.

Each time we have to check the size of groups. Once they come close to each other we stop moving kids around.

Take the first kid `0001` and check whether his 2nd choice is the lowest group. If it's a false then we move to the next one, and keep moving until we find one kid who's second choice is the lowest group (`A` in my example ).

'0011' and '0012' match our criteria so we can move them to the lowest group.

Checking for the length of the size of the most preferred group again.

and so on results in this ***`Step2`*** *`Module`* code:

```
Option Explicit

Type Group
    Name As String
    Column As String
    Size As Long
End Type

Type Number
    Total As Long
    Average As Long
    HiBound As Long
    LoBound As Long
End Type

Type Child
    Id As String
    Choice1 As String
    Choice2 As String
    Choice3 As String
End Type

Public A As Group
Public B As Group
Public C As Group

' moving based on the second preference
Sub Step_2()

    Dim T As Number

    A.Name = "A"
    A.Column = "F"
    A.Size = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    B.Name = "B"
    B.Column = "G"
    B.Size = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    C.Name = "C"
    C.Column = "H"
    C.Size = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    T.Total = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    T.Average = T.Total / 3
    T.HiBound = T.Average + 1
    T.LoBound = T.Average - 1

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim kidChoice As Range, kidId As Range

    For i = Range("" & getBiggest.Column & "" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        A.Size = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        B.Size = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        C.Size = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("" & getBiggest.Column & "" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = T.Average Or _
           Range("" & getSmallest.Column & "" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = T.Average _
        Then
            Exit For
        Else
            For k = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            Set kidChoice = Range("" & getBiggest.Column & "" & i)
                Set kidId = Range("A" & k)
                Dim kid As Child
                kid.Id = kidId.Text
                kid.Choice1 = getBiggest.Name
                If StrComp(kidChoice.Text, kidId.Text, 1) = 0 Then
                    For j = 1 To 3
                    If kidId.Offset(0, j) = 2 Then
                        kid.Choice2 = Cells(1, j + 1).Text
                    End If
                    If kidId.Offset(0, j) = 3 Then
                        kid.Choice3 = Cells(1, j + 1).Text
                    End If
                    Next j
                    If kid.Choice2 = getSmallest.Name Then
                        ' transfer groups
                        Dim nxtSmall As Long
                        nxtSmall = Range("" & getSmallest.Column & "" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        Range("" & getSmallest.Column & "" & nxtSmall).Value = kid.Id
                        kidChoice.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                End If
                Set kidId = Nothing
            Next k
            Set kidChoice = Nothing
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Function getBiggest() As Group
    If A.Size > B.Size And A.Size > C.Size Then
        getBiggest = A
    ElseIf B.Size > A.Size And B.Size > C.Size Then
        getBiggest = B
    ElseIf C.Size > A.Size And C.Size > B.Size Then
        getBiggest = C
    ElseIf A.Size = B.Size Or A.Size = C.Size Then
        getBiggest = A
    ElseIf B.Size = A.Size Or B.Size = C.Size Then
        getBiggest = B
    ElseIf C.Size = A.Size Or C.Size = B.Size Then
        getBiggest = C
    End If
End Function

Private Function getSmallest() As Group
    If A.Size < B.Size And A.Size < C.Size Then
        getSmallest = A
    ElseIf B.Size < A.Size And B.Size < C.Size Then
        getSmallest = B
    ElseIf C.Size < A.Size And C.Size < B.Size Then
        getSmallest = C
    ElseIf A.Size = B.Size Or A.Size = C.Size Then
        getSmallest = A
    ElseIf B.Size = A.Size Or B.Size = C.Size Then
        getSmallest = B
    ElseIf C.Size = A.Size Or C.Size = B.Size Then
        getSmallest = C
    End If
End Function
```

## Final result

And the final result of the equating the groups of kids preferred choices:
[image: final result]

I really hope this helps!

---

## Summary

If your sheet already looks like

[image: setup]

then run **`Step_1`** and then **`Step_2`**

I have ran this a few times for testing purposes, here are some sample results

---

## Your sample

*Random Votes + primary split into columns . Obviously, it isn't printing exactly the same results as you provided in your sample. You have already said there is no perfect solution. its ran on only 11 kids and you have said you have 100+. I think it does the job though and functions as expected*

executed **`Step_1`**

[image: your sample Step_1]

*Result*

[image: your sample Step_2]

## Sample 1

*Random Votes + primary split into columns*

executed **`Step_1`**

[image: sample 1 executed step_1]

*Result*

[image: result for sample 1]

## Sample 2

*Random Votes + primary split into columns*

executed **`Step_1`**

[image: sample 2 executed step_1]

*Result*

[image: sample 2 result executed step_2]

## Sample 3

*Random Votes + primary split into columns*

executed **`Step_1`**

[image: sample 3 executed step_1]

*Result*

[image: sample 3 result executed step_2]

Comment: I hear you. It wouldn't make sense to move someone of the mid size group with a first choice to an empty one; `0001` first choice is group C, that should not ever, in under any logical circumstances be moved to group A. I hope you see my point. And yes, `0009` seconds choice is group A so logically thinking it should move to group A. Number `0010` could also be moved programatically but I have not added this feature to avoid complexity. it is easily implementable anyway

Comment: Alright! sorry im late coming back to this conversation, but this looks like an excellent start to the solution im looking for. the 01/09 switch issue makes a lot of sense looking at it now. I made a mistake in the OP - and its one we often make when we get into the sorting of kids on paper. This works great for what im wanting to do. Im going to play play around with the script and see if i can make it flexible in a couple other ways, and i certainly appreciate the help, and will post back here with any changes i make.

Comment: @cecilgol well, I am glad this worked out for you. Yea, come back let us know what you've changed to achieve exactly what you needed. Good luck